# In EF 6.1 Custom Code First Conventions, which way is more efficient?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

I currently have a code that looks like this this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties<byte[]>()
        .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.IsType(typeof(BaseModel)) && 
                (p.Name == "Version"))
        .Configure(p => p.IsRowVersion());
}
```

and I just found a better way to write it like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Types<BaseModel>().Configure(a => a.Property(x => x.Version).IsRowVersion());
}
```

But my question is will it affect performance or reliability in any way?

Basically is 2nd piece of code a good equivalent of the 1st piece or are there any performance or reliability considerations that need to be taken into account?

Comment: The second is definitely easier to read for me, and looks a lot like http://romiller.com/2013/01/29/ef6-code-first-configuring-unmapped-base-types/

Comment: Thank you for the link, its very helpful indeed, as it shows a better way to configure multiple properties on the same type, as well as confirms that this is what other people use as well (and probably for a good reason too).